# How to correctly handle dropped connections with curl

Tags: php, curl

I'm using `curl_multi` to download files over what I can only describe as a "somewhat hindered internet type" of connection.

Using a default value for `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS` leaves the application hanging indefinitely. So, since the files are quite large (it takes about 20 minutes to download a 300kb file), I configure it with a suitable value of 1,800,000 (30mins). The problem is, if I lose the connection 5 minutes into the download, I have to wait 25 minutes for the handle to be released.

My initial idea to solve the problem was to use a smaller timeout, something in the region of 30 seconds then check `curl_info` for a timeout event. If it timeout, then restart the process using a range header.

There is a serious flaw here though, the server may see the multiple connections as a flood attempt and block me, or the server may not support the range header (forcing the download to start from the first byte).

Is there an alternative way to detect a lost or reset connection?

A point to note, my call to `curl_multi_select` uses a timeout value, so I am able to run code without having to wait on `curl` to release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `curl_multi_select` with a timeout, it seems that you should be able to use it to close the connection if any or all handles haven't received any data for a certain period of time.  The only problem is you don't know which handle hasn't received any data

```
$timeout      = 45; // abort after 45 seconds with no data
$lastReceived = 0;  // time data was last received

while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
    if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
        do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
            $lastReceived = time();
        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    } else {
        if ( time() - $lastReceived > $timeout ) {
            // no data received within timeout
            // close cURL handles & multi connection and restart
        }
    }
}
```

That could work but doesn't give you find grained control over specific handles.

The best way I've dealt with timeouts in a situation where I want to detect them long before a failure occurs is using `CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION` in conjunction with `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`.

I won't convert the code to the multi interface, but you can work it into your existing code based on your needs.

The idea is to define your own timeout and keep track of when the handle last received any data.  If no data has been received in that amount of time, then you can abort the transfer and try to start over.

I use this in production where data should be coming in every second so I want to detect timeouts early.  It works very well for all kinds of connection issues and testing showed it detected the timeouts much quicker than it would have taken for cURL to error out.

One side effect of using `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`, is that you'll have to save the data as it's read and not use `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to get the data from `curl_exec`

```
<?php

$readTimeout  = 45; // number of seconds to time out after if no data received
$lastReceived = 0;  // time data was last received on the handle
$buffer       = ''; // buffer for storing response (you'll need one for each handle)

//...when initializing cURL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, 'progressFunction');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'writeFunction');
// don't set anything for CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$info   = curl_getinfo($ch);
$error  = curl_errno($ch);
// $result will be false on any failure or timeout
// check $info['http_code'] for HTTP response status
// $error will be empty if no error occurred
// on success, $buffer will contain the full response body
// if failed, you can try reconnecting and resending the request until successful

//...

function writeFunction($handle, $data)
{
    global $lastReceived, $buffer; // <-- I use class properties instead

    $lastReceived = time();
    $size = strlen($data);

    $buffer .= $data;

    return $size;
}

function progressFunction($ch, $dltotal, $dlnow, $ultotal, $ulnow)
{
    global $lastReceived, $readTimeout;

    $time = time();

    if ($time - $lastReceived > $readTimeout) {
        // set error state - no data received within timeout
        return 1; // non-zero causes cURL to disconnect
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It's not terribly simple unfortunately, but it works well to do what you want to do.  Hope that helps.

Comment: The biggest problem I'm having with the timeout is that it ends the connection. Your proposed method of tracking the download size within time ranges works perfectly. Thanks for taking the time to write up a detailed answer.

Comment: You're welcome hope it helps.  My use case was pretty specific and I had other code both in the progressFunction and writeFunction to do other stuff that I removed for the example.  To expand, the connect/request logic lives in an infinite loop that basically runs forever and reconnects after a timeout/error (either forced from progressFunction or naturally from cURL).